# Advantages of Re-Compiling of Linux Kernels: Share your Ideas

Tags: linux, kernel, comparison, compile

can you give me some advantages of Recompilation of New Linux Kernel and Installations.

```
make xconfig modules modules_install install
```

this is what i`m talking on. can someone provide me the basic needs and Advantages?..
Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 5):

Generally, unless you need a specific option not compiled into a kernel, and/or need a smaller kernel optimised for size (say for an embedded system)... not much at all. Its one of those 'if you REALLY need to ask, it probably means you don't need to do it' things.

Answer (score 1):

Usually one only needs it if he got some problem and it can be solved with the kernel. But. There are so many advantages, one can't really list them.

Like:

- Faster boot (well if you sort out all the modules and use only "compiled-in" parts)
- Better security (you can patch the kernel to become more robust, secure)
- Create a real-time kernel (for multimedia purpose)
- Apply patchset like -mm or change scheduler (on some PC this can dramatically increase responsiviness)
- Changing the kernel to pre-empt for example can help in the terms of responsiviness also.
- You can enable/disable security (AppArmor for ex)
- You can enable/disable logging, debugging support  (both helps to make a smaller, a bit faster kernel if you dont need them.)

Just some of the sooo many options. On Ubuntu its really simple to create a new kernel. There is a nice howto about this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=311158

**You can read it how to configure it up here. Basically if you use** `make menuconfig` **and press** `?` **it'll throw out the relevant help for the given item.**